# How does sscanf separate a string into different variables?

Tags: c, scanf

Can someone explain how %25[^;] and %*[^ABCDF] are used in the following code?

```
char name[26], class[8];
int score;
char grade;
char record[50] = "Ross, Bob; MAC1234 85 A";

sscanf(record, "%25[ˆ;] %*c %6s %d %*[ˆABCDF] %c", name, class, &score, &grade);
```

Comment: Have you read the [documentation of `sscanf()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)?

Comment: BTW `%6s` --> `%7s` ?

Comment: And delete `%*[ˆABCDEF]`